# How to send flash message to user? (nodejs, express-validator, flash-connect)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using connect-flash and have an error:

```
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 2
```

Here is my code:

```
function (req, email, password, done){
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min:4});
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });

        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));

    }
```

the same, as this guy on video: https://youtu.be/js5hI2moBY4?list=PL55RiY5tL51rajp7Xr_zk-fCFtzdlGKUp&t=316 (timecode with this part of code)
But his code is working and my not. Why?

Comment: Reason in return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));, when i delete this, it's still working (but without validation-errors output)

Comment: could you provide the full error- stack, please?